# Find if a point is inside or outside flex primitive objects

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, primitive

I have some shaped created using flex primitive classes like ellipse , rectangle, path etc.

How can I find if a point is inside or outside these objects? (I need only the content area, not the transparent part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [hitTestPoint](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29) function is what you are looking for. Specify 3rd argument as `true`,and it will do the trick.

**UPDATE:** You need to wrap primitives by `Graphic` element, then perform checking with that element. *Example*:

```
<s:Graphic id="myEllipse">
    <s:Ellipse height="100" width="200">                              
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#000000" weight="1"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#0000FF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Ellipse>
</s:Graphic>

//......
myEllipse.hitTestPoint(someX,someY,true)
```

Comment: but this method is not available for primitives like ellipse, rect etc, as they don't inherit DisplayObject !!

Comment: This is fine. But how can I manage the empty area. Currently I am getting empty area also as true for the method. Is there any way to exclude the transparent area.

Comment: There is no code. When i create a diamond shape, the parent graphic object behaves as rectangle itself. So the 4 triangular edges(area not filled by diamond) still give valid result for the method. I need only the diamond area to respond, not the entire parent graphic. Hope u got the scenario?

Comment: @Saju How do you create the diamond shape? Is it picture, filled in rectangle?

Comment: I used 2 approaches.
1. Rotate square by 45 degree
2. draw a closed figure using path, with 4 equal sides.